# Unnecessary Foreign Key Constraint Failure

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc

So I have a mock database for a conference where I'm creating tables for the authors, papers, reviewers, etc.

The reviewers provide an email which refers to the Program Committee emails. This is the key constraint I put in place. Then I add data to the PC table and then attempt to add data to the reviewer table. This is the error I get:

```
Exception encountered com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`sampledb`.`review`, CONSTRAINT `review_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`email`) REFERENCES `pcmember` (`email`))
```

Here are the other functions:

```
public int loadPCMember(){
    String tablename = "pcmember";
    String create = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS pcmember(email VARCHAR(100), name VARCHAR(50), PRIMARY KEY (email));";
    makeTable(create);
    System.out.println("made table pcmember");
    //CSV Reader
    String[][] content = CSVReader(tablename,2);

    for(int i = 0 ; i < content.length; i++){
        try{
            String query = "INSERT INTO pcmember(email,name) VALUES (?,?)";
            PreparedStatement ps2 = net.prepareStatement(query);
            ps2.setString(1, content[i][0]);
            ps2.setString(2, content[i][1]);
            ps2.executeUpdate();
            System.out.println((i+1)+ " done");
        // Throw exception
        }catch (SQLException e){System.out.println("Exception encountered");return 0;}
    }
    System.out.println("PC Member Done");
    return 1;
}
//Load next
public int loadReview(){
    String tablename = "review";
    String create = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS review(reportid INTEGER, sdate DATE, comment VARCHAR(250), recommendation VARCHAR(6), paperid INTEGER NOT NULL, email VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(reportid), FOREIGN KEY (paperid) REFERENCES paper(paperid), FOREIGN KEY(email) REFERENCES pcmember(email));";
    makeTable(create);
    System.out.println("made table review");
    //CSV Reader
    String[][] content = CSVReader(tablename,6);

    for(int i = 0 ; i < content.length; i++){
        System.out.println("" + content[i][0] + "\t" +content[i][1] + "\t" + content[i][2] + "\t" +content[i][3] + "\t" +content[i][4] + "\t" +content[i][5]);
        try{
            //SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yy");
            //java.util.Date date = sdf.parse(content[i][1]);
            //System.out.println(""+date);
            //Date newDate = new Date(date.getTime());
            //System.out.println(""+newDate);
            String query = "INSERT INTO review(reportid,sdate,comment,recommendation,paperid,email) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)";
            PreparedStatement ps2 = net.prepareStatement(query);
            ps2.setInt(1, Integer.parseInt(content[i][0]));
            ps2.setDate(2, java.sql.Date.valueOf(content[i][1]));
            ps2.setString(3, content[i][2]);
            ps2.setString(4, content[i][3]);
            ps2.setInt(5, Integer.parseInt(content[i][4]));
            ps2.setString(6, content[i][5]);
            ps2.executeUpdate();
            System.out.println((i+1)+ " done");
        // Throw exception
        }catch (SQLException e){System.out.println("Exception encountered "+ e);return 0;
        }//catch (ParseException e){System.out.println("Parse Exception encountered "+e);}

    }
    System.out.println("Review Done");
    return 1;
}
```

I have a decent understanding of the key constraints and I'm pretty spot on with the CSV files having the same exact emails, so what could be causing this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm a SQL guy, not a Java guy.  If I ask or suggest anything that doesn't make sense because of that - you know why.  To be clear - based on that error message and the sql you have included it looks like you trying to insert a record into the review table that has an email address that doesn't exist in the pcmember table thus violating the foreign key constraint on the review table.  This seems like a data problem with the CVSs you are using. However since you mentioned that you are confident in the data files is it possible that the it's trying to INSERT the rows into the review table before the pcmember INSERT has successfully completed?

Comment: So how come the first foreign key reference is being passed without a hitch? I'm calling each of these functions one by one and that SHOULD be completing successfully before the next one is called.

Comment: When you say, "first foreign key reference" do you mean the reference to the paper table in your insert for review?